# Get the last element of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Consider I have following matrix

```
M <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
```

I just want to find the last element i.e `M[3, 3]`

As this matrix column and row size are dynamic we can't hardcode it to `M[3, 3]`

How can I get the value of last element?

Currently I've done using the below code

```
M[nrow(M), ncol(M)]
# [1] 9
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A matrix in R is just a vector with a `dim` attribute, so you can just subset it as one

```
M[length(M)]
## [1] 9
```

---

Though (as mentioned by @James) your solution could be more general in case you want to keep you matrix structure, as you can add `drop = FALSE`

```
M[nrow(M), ncol(M), drop = FALSE]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    9
```

Though, my solution could be also modified in a similar manner using the `dim<-` replacement function

```
`dim<-`(M[length(M)], c(1,1))
#      [,1]
# [1,]    9
```

---

Some **Benchmarks** (contributed by @zx8754)

```
M <- matrix(runif(1000000),nrow=1000)

microbenchmark(
  nrow_ncol={
    M[nrow(M),ncol(M)]
  },
  dim12={
    M[dim(M)[1],dim(M)[2]]
  },
  length1={
    M[length(M)]
  },
  tail1={
    tail(c(M),1)
  },
  times = 1000
)

# Unit: nanoseconds
#      expr     min      lq        mean    median      uq      max neval cld
# nrow_ncol     605    1209    3799.908    3623.0    6038    27167  1000   a 
#     dim12     302     605    2333.241    1811.0    3623    19922  1000   a 
#   length1       0     303    2269.564    1510.5    3925    14792  1000   a 
#    tail 1 3103005 3320034 4022028.561 3377234.0 3467487 42777080  1000   b
```

Comment: but the method proposed by op is perfectly okay and is slightly less obfuscating the intend.

Comment: @Roland I agree it's "OK" but I think OP doesn't realize he deals with just a vector and its important thing to realize when dealing with matrices in R.

Comment: Sure. My comment was merely an addendum. I've already upvoted (and had been preparing the same answer).

Comment: With the vector indexing method you can not avoid dropping the matrix class, which may be important.

Comment: @James `M[nrow(M), ncol(M)]` drops it too as for `attributes(M[nrow(M), ncol(M)])`, so not sure what you mean. It also seems like OP wants only the value, not the structure, do you read it otherwise?

Comment: You can add `drop=FALSE` to the multi-index version of `[`, but not to the single index one.

Comment: @James but then the output will be different from what OP asked for. I feel like you overcomplicating this, although it could be added to the answer if you insist. Btw, the `dim` attribute can be added afterwards if needed.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Benchmark clearly states that I can go ahead and use M[length(M)]. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SamuelAlexander What are you going to do with all those microseconds you will save compared to your method?

Comment: @Roland I just want to find whether the method I am using is the right way. Though the difference is in microseconds, now I am sure that I am using the right method to find the last element.

Comment: @SamuelAlexander There is no "right"  here. All methods can be used and three of them have the same performance for pretty much every purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather do:

```
tail(c(M),1)
# [1] 9
```

Comment: This is also a good solution, but you should explain that `c` removes all attributes (including the `dim` attribute) and thereby coerces the matrix into an atomic vector. `as.vector` is usually preferable for this (I remember a quote by B. Ripley regarding this).

Comment: interesting, did not experienced yet the attributes dismissal between `c` and `as.vector`

Comment: `as.vector` also removes all attributes if the result is atomic. The reason for using it is that the code is clearer.

Comment: @Roland the main problem with this method is that `c` creates a copy of the whole matrix you can validate with `tracemem`. Though the advantage is that it is more flexible when we want to select more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this and to avoid unnecessary repetition of the object name (or silly typos) would be to use pipes. Likes this:

```
require(magrittr)
M %>% .[nrow(.), ncol(.)]
##[1] 9
M %>% `[`(nrow(.), ncol(.))
##[1] 9
M %>% extract(nrow(.), ncol(.))
##[1] 9
```

The approaches are equivalent, so you can choose whichever feels more intuitive to you.